# How to normalize a vector with negative values using matlab?

Tags: matlab

For a given vector, say `v=[1 2 2]`, I need to normalize and the sum of all values in the resultant matrix must be 1. Then I am using the matlab code as `w=v/norm(v,1)`. Now the result `w=[0.2000 0.4000 0.4000]` i.e. `sum=0.2+0.4+0.4=1` and the condition is satisfied. But when using a negative value, the result is wrong. i.e. if `v=[1 -2 2]` and `w=v/norm(v,1)`. Now the result is `w=[0.2000 -0.4000 0.4000]` and `sum = 0.2+(-0.4)+0.4 != 1`.This sum is not equal to one. Then am using `w=abs(v)/norm(v,1)`. Is this correct?

Comment: I believe that is correct. Just beware that you are "throwing away" the information about the direction of the unit vector when you take the absolute value.

Comment: What exactly is your requirement for normalization? It can't be just to sum to 1, because [1 -2 2] already sums to 1...

Comment: Depends on what exactly is your purpose. Maybe @Dan 's answer hepls you, if not, explain more what is your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider subtracting the lowest value:

```
V = v - min(v)
W = V/norm(V,1)
```

now `sum(W)` does equal `1` and you won't be discarding information like you would if you use `abs`

Comment: @darthbith I don't think that's a requirement. What it does it normalize the vector so that its elements sum to 1. Of course `V` and `v` have different `norm`s

Comment: I guess it depends on what the OP is going for. If he wants the length of the unit vector in the direction of the original vector (which is 1 by definition), the `abs` method should be correct. That's what I assumed. With no snark intended (i.e. out of curiosity :-)), when would normalizing the vector by this method be useful?

Comment: Of course, by taking the 1-norm, he is not getting the unit vector, so maybe I'm completely off here! :-D

Comment: @darthbith I don't know when it would be useful. I would usually normalize to fit my data to a range (e.g. btw -1 and 1). This is just one way to make sure the values are all btw 0 and 1 AND that they sum to 1. I don't know why that's useful, it's just how I interpreted the question.

Comment: @dan suppose v=[1 -2 2] and using the code V = v - min(v), W = V/norm(V,1), the result W=[0.4286         0    0.5714]. now the sum is one. But one element is zero. Next step in my project is W*S.ie, take each element in W and multiplied by S.Now the second element in W=0, so it return all the elements aS zero...how to correct it???plz help me....

Comment: @user3148302 Can't help you until you define your requirements properly. What is `S`?? Explain your over all goal here please.

Comment: @darthbith Would calculating the unit vector use `norm(v,2)`? Perhaps this is what the OP wants. `norm(v/norm(v,2),2)` does equal 1. And that might make more sense than making the sum equal 1.

Comment: @Dan yes, the unit vector is defined as `v./sqrt(sum(v.^2))` which is equivalent to the 2-norm. By definition, the `sum(abs(unit_vector))` is one. But by taking the `abs` you lose the information about which way the unit vector is pointing. Nonetheless, the OP needs to make his wants clear.

Comment: @dan I am doing a project namely "single image super resolution with multiscale similarity learning" , as a part my curriculum.Now i am dividing two image LR( low resolution) and HR(high resolution) into 5*5 patches. Then finding weight between them. This weight is normalized and the resultant value is multiplied by each LR patch to form next level HR image.For this purpose iam doing normalization.So when the normalized value is zero, then next multiplication result is also zero...That is the problem..help me...

Comment: Became more clear, but still, what do you mean "Then finding weight between them. This weight is normalized and the resultant value is multiplied by each LR patch to form next level HR image" ?

Comment: GW=R,solving this linear equation we find the weight.Where G is 3*3 matrix,R is 3*1 vector which contain all ones and W is the resultant weight vector.Here W is 3*1 vector.Then we normalize the weight vector W in such a way that sum of each element in W (ie,Wij) is equal to 1.Then taking each weight and multiplied with each 5*5 patch.

Answer (score 0):

`norm(v,1)` ignores sign (it computes `sum(abs(v))`). To make the sum of the vector equal 1, you could use

```
w = v/sum(v);
```

Comment: when using this , if sum(v)==0 then w=inf